# How can I delay execution until after os.system finishes?

Tags: python, file, os.system

I am using `os.system` to copy a file from a system to another. The logic of a very simple program is to execute another set of commands after this file gets copied.

The problem is that `os.system` does not actually wait for the file to be copied, and gets to executing the next line. This causes issues to the system. I could actually give some wait functions, through `time.sleep()`, but we have to copy files with sizes ranging from 500 MB to sometimes 20 GB, and the times taken are very different.

What's the solution? I need to somehow tell my program that the files are copied, and then to execute the next line.

Comment: Don't use `os.system` for copying files.

Comment: os.system does wait for the command to complete.  What command are you using for the copy?

Comment: Does "from a system to another" mean via the network?  What protocol?  Or is it from on file system to another?

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I'd try is to use [`shutil.copyfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) instead of an external program to copy the file.  If you have to use an external program, you should call it via [`subprocess.Popen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), not via `os.system()`.  You can use the `Popen.wait()` to wait for the subprocess to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rather use [shutil.copyfile](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) than `os.system` to copy a file.

(Edit: woops, copy, not move)

Comment: -1 He said "from a system to another".  shutil only works on the same system.

Comment: @payne: Depends. You can move items from one system to another using NFS or SSHFS mounts, for instance. OP didn't provide much details.

Comment: Technically true.  But at this stage, we're both guessing what's in the OP's head. :-)

Answer (score 1):

use the [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) module for copying files.

> The shutil module offers a number of
>   high-level operations on files and
>   collections of files. In particular,
>   functions are provided which support
>   file copying and removal.

also, use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module instead of os.system()

> The subprocess module allows you to
>   spawn new processes, connect to their
>   input/output/error pipes, and obtain
>   their return codes. This module
>   intends to replace several other,
>   older modules and functions, such as:
>
> os.system

for a better answer, you need to provide more detail about what exactly you are trying to do and how (programmatically) you are stuck.