# Issues with subprocess.Popen() replacing os.system()

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to generate a set of files through a python script on a 48-core cluster which actually has a master-and 3 slave machines. I need to generate a set of files, run some scripts on them, collect results and then delete them. I again repeat the process- regenerate files, execute, delete etc.,
When I delete and regenerate files with the same name, I see that the slave machine complains that it cannot find the files.
I am running python script through `os.system()`

I learnt from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837127/how-can-i-delay-execution-until-after-os-system-finishes) that it is better to use `subprocess.Popen()` rather than `os.system` so that it actually waits for my script to generate my files, before proceeding with the execution. I could use `os.system("pause")` or `time.sleep(whatever)` for waiting, but I want to convert my os.systems to subprocess.popens or subprocess.calls and I am stuck here.

I ran through the python documentation and tried out `subprocess.Popen('ls')`, but I am not able to get a simple thing like `subprocess.Popen('cd /whatever_directory')` working.

It might sound silly but how do I execute such a simple command like `cd` through `subprocess` rather than `os.system('cd')`?

Then, I actually want to convert the following into subprocess. How do I do it?

```
import os,optparse
from optparse import OptionParser

parser.add_option("-m", "--mod",dest='module', help='Enter the entity name')
parser.add_option("-f", "--folder", dest="path",help="Enter the path")

module=options.module
path=options.path

os.system('python %s/python_repeat_deckgen_remote.py -m %s' %(path,module))
```

I just replaced os.system with subprocess.Popen.
But it gave me a lot of complaints:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As NPE already noted, new processes don't affect the existing one (which means `os.system('cd /some/where')` also has no effect on the current process).  In this case, though, I think you're tripping over the fact that `os.system` invokes a shell to interpret the command you pass in, while `subprocess.Popen` does not do so **by default**.  But you can tell it to do so:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    'python %s/python_repeat_deckgen_remote.py -m %s' % (path, module),
    shell = True)
status = proc.wait()
```

If you're invoking a shell built-in command or using shell expansions, it's necessary to invoke the shell (assuming you're not willing to simulate it):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> x = subprocess.Popen('echo $$')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>> x = subprocess.Popen('echo $$', shell = True); x.wait()
81628
0
>>>
```

but you can bypass the shell—which can help with security issues—if your problem permits, by breaking up the command arguments into a list:

```
>>> x = subprocess.Popen(['echo', '$$']); x.wait()
$$
0
>>>
```

Note that this time the output here is the string `$$`, rather than a process ID, since this time the shell did not interpret the string.

For your original example, for instance, you might use:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python',
    os.path.join(path, 'python_repeat_deckgen_remote.py'),
    '-m',
    module])
```

which avoids issues if `path` and/or `module` contain characters special to the shell.

(You might even want to call `subprocess.Popen` with `cwd = path` and eliminate the call to `os.path.join`, although that depends on other things.)

Answer (score 2):

> I am not able to get a simple thing like `subprocess.Popen('cd /whatever_directory')` working.

Each process's current working directory is independent of other processes in the system.

When you start a subprocess (using either of these mechanisms), and get it to `cd` into another directory, that has no effect on the parent process, i.e. on your Python script.

To change the current working directory of your script, you should use [`os.chdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir).

Comment: I understand that I can use os.chdir(). But my question is that- I want to run commands using subprocess instead of os.system. An example I used was: os.system('cd') works, where 'cd' is the command I am referring to. So, how do I replace os.system with subprocess in this case.

And similarly, I have run python commands using os.system('python *.py). I want to replace os.system with subprocess and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I might be not answering you question directly, but for such tasks which require running subprocess, I always use [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org).

IMO, It makes the task much simpler and more intuitive, including running on remote machines.

Using plumbum, in order to set subprocess's working directory, you can run the command in a `with local.cwd(path): my_cmd()` context.